# If a motherboard can support 3rd & 2nd generation processor, can it support 1st generation processors?

Tags: cpu, core

I have just bought a core i3 first generation(`Intel® Core™ i3-530 Processor (4M Cache, 2.93 GHz Socket LGA1156`) but I looked up the website of the motherboard(H61M-K ASUS) and it showed me this:-

```
    Intel® Socket 1155 for 3rd/2nd Generation Core™ i7/Core™ i5/Core™ i3/Pentium®/Celeron® Processors

Supports Intel® 22 nm CPU

Supports Intel® 32 nm CPU

Supports Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 

Supports CPU up to 77 W
```

it says it can support 1155 socket core i3 2nd/3rd generation but mine is 1156 core i3 1st generation. Will the processor work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; there is a physical incompatibility between [LGA 1156](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1156) and [LGA 1155](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1155).

From Wikipedia:

> Processors for LGA 1155 and LGA 1156 sockets are not compatible with
>   each other since they have different socket notches.

Comment: Well, I think it's a bit more than just different socket notches. It's not possible to make it work just by changing the notches so that it physically fits in the socket - that's a recipe for something going 'bang'.